# windows phone 8 wav does not run when app is run

Tags: c#, xaml, audio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I was trying to implement the sample app of running a wav file as shown in the microsoft virtual academy tutorial for beginners. I tried implement same code and ran app but my app does not play sound of wav file. I am running the app on emulator. and following is the code i implemented in xaml file:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="Quack" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="128" Margin="314,218,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"
                  Source="/Assets/quack.wav"
                  AutoPlay="True" Balance="1" Volume="1"/>
```

following is code in xaml.cs file

```
 private void buttonQuack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textQuack.Text = "Hear the sound";
        QuackMediaElement.Play();
    }
```

I just wondered if is there any setting required in emulator in order to enable volume or something

Comment: Where is `QuackMediaElement` declared, it looks like it should be named Quack instead. Try `Quack.Play()`

Comment: i tried making it Quack.Play() but still didn't worked. having said this.. I debugged it by displaying an image added in assets folder and that worked. It was just to see if it is able to access the file correctly and it worked. Not sure why wav file is not working.

Comment: It should play automatically if AutoPlay is set to true.  Post your full XAML code, I have a suspicion that it is not correct.  Also if you can screenshot the Solution Explorer file structure for us, it will determine if you're placing it into the right location.

Comment: Hi, So what I did is took the same file(used in the tutorial) and tried running app and it worked. strangely, if you use other wav files even some of those from windows itself, those wont work, but the ones provided by channel9 msdn did worked.